# Laravel get all the values of a column beginning with a number

Tags: image, laravel

I have a model called "Image" and a table called "images". The table has a column for the "id" and another for the "name". I need to fetch only the rows with the name beginning with a number.

I need to fetch are called something like

```
16783521_facebook.png
```

While the others are something like...

```
twiter.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Image::whereRaw("name REGEXP '^[0-9]'") -> get();
```

If it's something you're going to use in more than 1 place, consider moving it to a scope.

In your image model define something like:

```
public function scopeNumeric($query)
{
    return $query -> whereRaw("name REGEXP '^[0-9]'");
}
```

Then you can just use:

```
Image::numeric() -> get();
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont know much about laravel, but this plain query will help -

> SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn REGEXP '^[0-9]+$' or
>   SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE col1 REGEXP '[0-9]+';

Comment: I need the solution in Laravel as we dont use raw queries but any way the option for regular expression I will take it and check.

Comment: Neither of those regexes will actually work for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel doesn't have that built-in, so you'll have to make do with raw queries. In its base form:

```
$results = SomeModel::whereRaw("some_column REGEXP '^[0-9]'")->get();
```

You can modify this as usual with selects, other limitations, etc. as you require.

Answer (score 0):

Filter the images after the query using one of the collection methods. Like below solved me.

```
$onlyNumeric = $photos->filter(function ($value, $key) {
return is_numeric(substr($value, 0, 1));
});
```

Comment: Yes - but be aware that if there's a lot of results that is an *incredibly* inefficient method of doing it!